# ¿Qué significa el operador += en Winforms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

La verdad es que me causa mucha confusión ver este tipo de operadores, no sé lo que significa o para qué se coloca.

```
checkedit1.CheckStateChanged += CheckValorSi_CheckStateChanged;
```

Comment: Es un acumulador, es como que tengas `variable = variable + otravariable` Se usa cuando quieres por ejemplo calcular la suma de alguna columna. Etc.

Comment: Depende en que se use , puede ser un suma acumulativa o simplemente suscribirse a eventos

Comment: Se les conocen como operadores de asignaciones, fueron creados en los albores de la programación con la intención de simplificar (abreviar) las operaciones aritméticas estándar, puedes conocer más sobre operadores en este [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Operadores_de_C_y_C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como han comentado otros compañeros, el operador += es un operador acumulativo, lo que está a la derecha se acumula (o suma, si son datos numéricos) a lo que está a la izquierda.

En ese caso específico lo que se está haciendo es "acumular" un delegado (lo que está a la derecha) a un evento (lo que está a la izquierda).

Tu puedes "acumular/sumar" delegados a un evento, y cada vez que el evento se dispare, todos los delegados que se "acumulen/sumen" al evento se van  ejecutar. Lo de la derecha es un delegdo, es decir, un método.

También puedes "acumular/sumar" delegados anónimos al evento:

```
 checkedit1.CheckStateChanged += (sender, e) => { /* aqui iría el código del delegado */ };
```

Puedes también "eliminar/restar" delegados a un evento:

```
checkedit1.CheckStateChanged -= CheckValorSi_CheckStateChanged;
```

Muy util para no tener fugas de memoria (memory leaks) que se pueden dar bajo ciertas condiciones.

Cuando tu pones un botón en un formulario y le das doble click, el diseñador de formularios hace eso que pusiste, crea un delegado (método) que generalmente lo llama algo así como "private void button_Click" y lo acumula al evento Click del botón que le diste doble click, solo que el código que genera donde pone el += lo pone en otro archivo.

Los eventos se utilizan no solo en winforms, son parte del contenido que puede tener cualquier clase, como las propiedades, los campos (fields) o los métodos. Tu mismo puedes definir un evento en tus clases, sin siquiera utilizar winforms.

Por último, intenta leer la documentación que pusieron los otros compañeros, es realmente necesario conocer sobre eventos y delegados, sobretodo creando aplicaciones con GUI.

Answer (score 18):

En tu caso al `checkedit1.CheckStateChanged` le estas suscribiendo el evento `CheckValorSi_CheckStateChanged;` mediante el operador [`+=`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator)

> - [Suscribirse a un evento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb166557.aspx)
> - [Cómo: Suscribir y cancelar la suscripción a eventos (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms366768(v=vs.80).aspx)

Mira ejemplos aqui:

```
a += b
```

es lo mismo que

```
a = a + b
```

Etc ...

asi que

```
a -= b es equivalente a: a = a - b
a *= b es equivalente a: a = a * b
a /= b es equivalente a: a = a / b
```

> Familiarícese con los operadores en C # [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Answer (score 15):

Una expresión que usa el operador **+=**, como

```
x + = y     //checkedit1.CheckStateChanged += CheckValorSi_CheckStateChanged;
```

es equivalente a

```
x = x + y   //checkedit1.CheckStateChanged = checkedit1.CheckStateChanged + CheckValorSi_CheckStateChanged;
```

excepto que x solo se evalúa una vez. El significado del [operador **+**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator) depende de los tipos de **x** e **y** (adición para operandos numéricos, concatenación para operandos de cadena, etc.).

El operador **+=** no se puede sobrecargar directamente, es decir debe incializarse con un valor inicialmente.

El operador **+=** también se usa para especificar un método que será llamado en respuesta a un evento; tales métodos se llaman manejadores de eventos. El uso del operador += en este contexto se denomina [suscripción a un evento](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events).

---

Referencia: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator

Comment: Sabes, con unos arreglos, con el ultimo párrafo hubiese sido suficiente.

Comment: Cierto, pero mientras más info mejor ;)

Comment: Pero quedó bstante confuso así como lo explicaste

Comment: Para mí la respuesta es perfecta. Me habría parecido incompleta si solo hubiera tenido el último párrafo. A mi parecer sería más confuso (e incluso incorrecto) dar una explicación parcial del operador.

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez Si ya conoces del lenguaje entenderás, pero para alguien que no conozca bien el lenguaje realmente es confuso. Por ejemplo, el término sobrecargar no está explicado así que puede confundir a alguien que apenas está aprendiendo.

Answer (score 4):

El operador += indica que la variable se va a sumar a si misma.  Es equivalente a esto:

```
checkedit1.CheckStateChanged = checkedit1.CheckStateChanged + CheckValorSi_CheckStateChanged;
```

Comment: El checkedit1 es un control checkbox pero de DevExpress lo que no se es para que se utiliza esa asignación. Esta sumando algo en realidad ?

Comment: Entonces creo que lo que esta haciendo es creando el evento CheckStateChanged de ese control. Lo raro es que no usa el new. Deberas explicar un poco mas el contexto

Comment: @LuisFernando No es necesario utilizar new cuando se subscribe a un evento.

Comment: @LuisFernando Aparte no "crea" un evento, el evento ya existe.

Answer (score 4):

Se trata de una asignación de adición. Agrega el valor de la variable de la derecha a la izquierda. Si ambos son números se suman, si al menos uno es un string se concatenan.

Aquí tienes más información sobre los distintos operadores:
[Expresiones y operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: Lo único que en el caso del OP, no es una suma sino una subscripcion a un evento.

Comment: En este caso no son ni números no string, así que no aplica la explicación en ese sentido

Answer (score 2):

### Operadores de Asignaciones

Se les conocen como [operadores de asignaciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Assignment_Operators), fueron creados en los albores de la programación con la intención de simplificar (abreviar) las operaciones aritméticas estándar. Actualmente son soportados por la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación.

### Tabla de Operadores

```
Operador     Descripcion        Abreviacion para:
  =           Asignacion         x = y
 +=           Adicion            x = x + y
 -=           Sustraccion        x = x - y
 *=           Multiplicacion     x = x * y
 /=           Division           x = x / y
```

Todos operan bajo una semántica similar.

### Ejemplo

```js
var x = 10, y = 2;

// Asignación para:
console.log( x += y); // Adición         (resultado 12)
console.log( x -= y); // Sustracción     (resultado 10)
console.log( x *= y); // Multiplicación  (resultado 20)
console.log( x /= y); // División        (resultado 10)
```

Y como siempre hay una excepción a la regla y es el operador de asignación para la adición `+=`, el cual se utiliza también para concatenar (unir) cadenas de variables.

### Ejemplo

```js
var x = "Valor: ", y = 2;

// Asignación para:
console.log( x += y); // cadenas de variables (resultado "Valor: 2")
console.log( x -= y); // cadenas de variables (resultado "NaN")
console.log( x *= y); // cadenas de variables (resultado "NaN")
console.log( x /= y); // cadenas de variables (resultado "NaN")
```

En algunos lenguajes de programación moderna orientada a objetos se le ha dado una nueva connotación un poco ortodoxa (como siempre Microsoft lleva la batuta), y es la de **suscribirse a eventos** la cual esta de mas explicada en anteriores respuestas.

Answer (score -1):

Es el equivalente a escribir :
    a = a + b;
En cuyo caso se puede escribir asi:
    a += b;

Comment: Aunque esta publicación provee una respuesta a la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Además, no aporta mucho más a lo que ya se ha indicado en las otras 6 respuestas. Deberías editarla para añadir más detalles o información adicional. Lee [answer] para más información.